# Javascript hover addclass not working after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, menu, hover

I created a menu and when you hover a child item, then some content will showing up.

The only problem is when after calling Ajax. It looks like the javascript is not working inside this Ajax call.

```js
$.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.nav-menu li').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('showcontentblock')
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('showcontentblock')
  });
});
```

Comment: Does the AJAX call add new `li` elements? If so you need to use a delegated event handler. Although note that you shouldn't be using JS to add/remove classes on hover events - CSS is far better for that.

Comment: The javascript is adding the class when you hover the li element. The added class is a whole CSS code with display block function, which will show the content. I will try your idea with hover as CSS. To ask your first question, no, Ajax is not calling li.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the element(s) do not exist on page load or prior to the AJAX call you can bind event listeners using `$(document).on` and pass the selectors as the second argument. This replaces the legacy methods `.live` and `.delegate`

```
$.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.nav-menu')
    .on('mouseenter', 'li', function(){
      $(this).addClass('showcontentblock');
    })
    .on('mouseleave', 'li', function(){
      $(this).removeClass('showcontentblock');
    });
});
```

I also agree that should be handled with CSS only.

```
.nav-menu li:hover {
  // copy+paste showcontentblock styles
}
```

It seems like you're dynamically adding these menus. Try this pure CSS approach to the nav-menu.

```css
.nav-menu {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: sticky;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.nav-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-menu li.sub-menu:hover > .nav-items {
  display: block;
}

.nav-menu li a,
.nav-menu li span {
  color: #131313;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-menu li.sub-menu > span {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.nav-menu li.sub-menu > span:after {
  content: "\f054";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
}

/* main navigation items */
.nav-menu > li.sub-menu > span:after {
  content: "\f078";
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  margin-top: 4px;
}

.nav-menu li a:hover,
.nav-menu li span:hover {
  background: #eee;
}

.nav-menu .nav-items {
  display: none;
}

.nav-items {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #e9e9e9, 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0, .1);
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 1px 4px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 9;
}

.nav-items li {
  display: block;
}

.nav-items li a,
.nav-items li span {
  display: block;
  color: #131313;
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav-menu .nav-items > li.sub-menu:hover > .nav-items {
  display: block;
}

.nav-menu .nav-items .nav-items {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<ul class="nav-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="">
      Home
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-menu">
    <span>Solutions</span>
    <ul class="nav-items">
      <li>
        <a href="">Marketing</a>
      </li>      
      <li class="sub-menu">
        <span>Products</span>
        <ul class="nav-items">
          <li class="sub-menu">
            <span>Email Signatures</span>
            <ul class="nav-items">
              <li>
                <a href="">Compliance</a>
              </li>
              <li class="sub-menu">
                <span>Tracking</span>
                <ul class="nav-items">
                  <li>
                    <a href="">Analytics</a>
                  </li>      
                  <li>
                    <a href="">GDPR</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="">Reporting</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">Integrations</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried your first javascript code. I don't work, I also have no errors in devtools. Using Jquery 1.9.2. According to your second fix, this is what I prefer in the first instance but how I can do it with a hidden div inside <li><div>**content**</div></li> When you will hover li it needs to show another div.

Comment: I've updated the jQuery code and provided a pure CSS solution. If the jQuery code isn't working than the selectors must be incorrect or the snippet needs to be wrapped in the DOM ready callback. Let me know if either one help.

Comment: Well, this worked for my. I used only .nav-menu li.sub-menu:hover > .nav-items { display: block; } to show just the div inside the li element, which is working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should put code you want to run after an Ajax call within the `success`, `error` or `complete` property of your Ajax method.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: "www.url.com",
    success: function (response) {
        // Run code on success
    },
    error: function (error) {
        // Run code on error
    },
    complete: function () {
        // Run code no matter the outcome
        $('.nav-menu li').hover(function() {
            $(this).addClass('showcontentblock');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your question. I have another type of Ajax, so I don't know how I can add this. Here you can see it: https://www.screencast.com/t/ldoUgsnAD4